# Конвертировать hex в символы

Tags: php, hex

Мне нужно конвертировать строку вида
`cff0e8` в строку `При`. Есть ли готовые функции для php?

Я не смог найти, буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: а каким образом из `cff0e8` надо получить `При`?

Comment: насколько я понял, это hex

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.hex2bin.php

Comment: "При" в hex  = d09fd180d0b8

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php
$hex_str = "cff0e8";
$out_str  = "";
while ( strlen($hex_str) > 0 ) {
    $out_str .= hex2bin( substr( $hex_str, 0, 2) );
    $hex_str = substr( $hex_str, 2, strlen( $hex_str ) - 2);
}
echo mb_convert_encoding($out_str, "utf-8", "cp1251")."\n";
```

> Результат: При